# Variable Substitution in Awk Print Statement -v

Tags: awk, cut, variable-substitution

I've spent over an hour poking at this. It can't be this hard...
I want to print a column of data from one file to another file. The column I want to print is dependent on what is passed in and stuff happening earlier in the script, but it is called COL. The file I need to pull the information from is called $1.db, $1 being the first argument passed in (already checked that it exists).
What I have currently:

```
awk -v colvar="$COL" '{ print $colvar }' "$1.db"  >> tmp2.tmp
```

This results in the entire contents of $1.db being printed to tmp2.tmp, not just the column.

When I sh -xv it, I see

```
awk -v colvar="$COL" '{ print $colvar }' "$1.db"  >> tmp2.tmp
+ awk -v colvar=3 '{ print $colvar }' cop4342.db
```

So, I see that the awk var is being set to the value of COL, but it isn't being substituted inside the print statement. I suspect that is due to the single quotes, but don't know what to do about it. Any help appreciated : )

Comment: Are you sure you have `FS` set correctly?

Comment: I don't know what FS signifies in this context, so I'm going to go with no... I'm new to this.

Comment: If you're referring to my file privileges, I have confirmed earlier in the script that I have read and write privileges on all files I'm referencing.

Comment: `FS` is the field-separator, e.g. if you have comma-separated data call `awk` with `-F,`. It's hard to tell you more without some sample input. I recommend you read the the awk manual page `man awk`.

Comment: The field separator is a single space - the default for awk. I'll add sample input to the question. I've read the man page, just didn't remember the term FS. Thanks for taking a look at it for me.

Comment: That's good. The reason I asked is that your `awk` program works here as it is.

Comment: Good to know that it runs, now I'm confused why it doesn't run on my machine. Whatever - I'm just going to use the cut workaround suggested below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It works for me. How about running it from command line to test it?

Comment: What's your OS and version of awk. Also, which awk are you running (output of `type awk`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is extract a column of data, you can just use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut). For example, if file `example.dat` contains

```
a b c d e
1 2 3 4 5
```

then `cut -d ' ' -f 3 example.dat` gives

```
c
3
```

The field separator here is a space, and we are selecting column three.

*Edit:* This bash script calls awk to produce the equivalent output:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1

awk '{print $colvar}' colvar=$1 example.dat
```

Comment: I'm feeling really dumb right about now. Thanks! For knowledge sake, any idea what is wrong with the awk I wrote?

Comment: The problem is I don't know what col it will be. The column number is a variable which is set earlier in the script.

Comment: @Lauren - see my edit, which accepts a variable and works here.